# How to iterate Queue.Queue items in Python?

Tags: python, queue, producer-consumer

Does anyone know a pythonic way of iterating over the elements of a `Queue.Queue` *without* removing them from the Queue. I have a producer/consumer-type program where items to be processed are passed by using a `Queue.Queue`, and I want to be able to print what the remaining items are. Any ideas?

Answer (score 52):

You can loop over a copy of the underlying data store:

```
for elem in list(q.queue)
```

Eventhough this bypasses the locks for Queue objects, the list copy is an atomic operation and it should work out fine.

If you want to keep the locks, why not pull all the tasks out of the queue, make your list copy, and then put them back.

```
mycopy = []
while True:
     try:
         elem = q.get(block=False)
     except Empty:
         break
     else:
         mycopy.append(elem)
for elem in mycopy:
    q.put(elem)
for elem in mycopy:
    # do something with the elements
```

Comment: `for elem in list(q.queue)` results in `TypeError: 'Queue' object is not iterable` in Python 3. Perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Comment: @macmadness86 It looks like you have another layer with "q" being code object that has a "queue" attribute that holds a Queue object.  Try this:  ``for elem in list(q.queue.queue)``.

Comment: Roger that. Will comply. Thanks for the tip. (this message is scheduled for deletion)

Answer (score 24):

Listing queue elements without consuming them:

```
>>> from Queue import Queue
>>> q = Queue()
>>> q.put(1)
>>> q.put(2)
>>> q.put(3)
>>> print list(q.queue)
[1, 2, 3]
```

After operation, you can still process them:

```
>>> q.get()
1
>>> print list(q.queue)
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can subclass `queue.Queue` to achieve this in a thread-safe way:

```
import queue


class ImprovedQueue(queue.Queue):
    def to_list(self):
        """
        Returns a copy of all items in the queue without removing them.
        """

        with self.mutex:
            return list(self.queue)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the deque into a list before printing the elements so that you can easily iterate through it.

```
from collections import deque

d = deque([7,9,3,5])

d.append(2)
d.appendleft(1)
d.append(10)
d.pop()

for elem in list(d):
    print(elem, end=" ")

#Output: 1 7 9 3 5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an `IterableQueue(asyncio.Queue)` that supports `async for` iteration. See [pyutils](https://github.com/Jylpah/pyutils) in [GitHub](https://github.com/Jylpah/pyutils).

```
from pyutils import IterableQueue
from asyncio import run, Task, create_task

async def producer(Q: IterableQueue[int], n: int) -> None:
    await Q.add_producer(N=1) 
    for i in range(n):
        await Q.put(i)
    await Q.finish()
    return None

async def amain():
    q : IterableQueue[int] = IterableQueue(maxsize=5)
    task : Task = create_task(producer(q, 10))
    # Iterate over queue items
    async for i in q:
        print(f"Got {i}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run(amain())
```

`IterableQueue()` counts producers with `add_producer()`. Once the last producers finishes (`finish()`) then a sentinel value (`None`) is added to the queue marking the queue end.