# Python Queues - Put returning None

Tags: python, python-2.7

Been trying to read documentation and looking at online examples but my queue still returning None.

```
    from collections import defaultdict
    from Queue import Queue 

    -- in my init

    self.tickerPrices = dict()
    queue = Queue(maxsize=5)
    queue.put((0.00097073, 67689.70942763))
    self.tickerPrices['a'] = queue

    def appendToTickerDict(self, tickerid, askprice, volume):
      if(tickerid in self.tickerPrices):
            tickerQueue = self.tickerPrices[tickerid].put((askprice, volume))  --RETURNS NONE
```

tickerQueue returns None. Before this step, I tested it and saw that if I add something to this queue in the init, it shows up with .get before executing this code

Any tips would be most helpful.

Comment: `put()` is not meant to return anything but because every Python function has to return something it returns `None`

Comment: See the [documentation for `Queue.put`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.put). It does not return anything.

Comment: Right. The [documentation for `Queue.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get) states that it removes and returns an item from the queue.

Comment: @Galen is there a way to iterate over the Queue without actually removing the element?

Comment: That is typically not the use of Queue. It sounds like you want something like a list. However, if you need the Queue for something else, see [How to iterate Queue.Queue items in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8196254/how-to-iterate-queue-queue-items-in-python).

Comment: @Galen that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see python language references [expression-statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#expression-statements).